# Programmatically create a keyboard shortcut in python

Tags: python, windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm creating the setup for a script. I need the setup to include a keyboard shortcut to the script itself. Basically an easy way to do this would be to use Windows 7 equivalent to Ubuntu's `bind` command. How can I do this in Python?

What I've tried:

I read somewhere that creating a `vcst` file will allow me to make keybindings, so I tried this:

```
def run_setup(self):
    with open(self.file_name, 'a+') as vsct:
        vsct.write("""<KeyBindings>
 <KeyBinding guid="esc_tool" id="c:\users\{}\desktop\esc_tool\main.py"
        key1="8" mod1="CONTROL" mod2="ALT"/>
</KeyBindings>
            """.format(getpass.getuser()))
```

That didn't work.

How can I do this successfully?

**EDIT**

The above seems a little confusing, so what I want to do is create a keyboard shortcut to a script called `main.py` from inside of a script called `setup.py`. So:

`python setup.py` creates a keyboard shortcut with the keys CNTRL-ALT-8 to a script called `main.py`. So when the user presses CNTRL-ALT-8 it runs `main.py` in the Python interpreter.

Comment: Can you edit this to be more descriptive so I can come up with an answer that helps you.

Comment: @Harrison Just did

Answer (score 0):

Do you mind if `setup.py` is an AutoHotkey script instead, i.e. `setup.ahk`?

Downside: you have to install an extra program ([AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/download/)) if you don't already have it.

Upside: the script is tiny:

```
^!8::            ;defines the shortcut as Ctrl+Alt+8 (Ctrl is ^, Alt is !)
     RunWait, python "C:\Path\To\Your\Script\main.py"
Return
```

Note: this assumes python is in the PATH environment variable; otherwise use the full path to python.exe in row 2.